# http mod deflate compression works on some but not all CSS files?

Tags: css, apache, compression, gzip, deflate

I'm trying to get mod deflate and gzip setup on my server. It's all working swimmingly but it does not appear be be catching all files. It's not that it is missing ALL javascript or ALL CSS. It appears to be missing some javascript and some CSS.

For example, the following CSS IS NOT being compressed:
    http://www.discussthemarket.com/global-assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css

Whereas the following CSS IS being compressed:
    http://www.discussthemarket.com/assets/css/bootstrap.default.css

Here is my config in my `htaccess`:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

I have googled til the cows come home and nothing is working. I've also tried various variations on the config above all in vain.

Answer (score -1):

Well I have found the solution though I do not know why it is working:

## solution

removed the htaccess directives and created a conf.d file instead on server :\

```
# DEFLATE by type - html, text, css, xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml

# DEFLATE by type - javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/x-javascript

# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
```